# An error I receive when trying to launch Unity / Unreal Engine (API-MS-WIN-CRT-MATH)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4

I've tried reinstalling both softwares, as it said in the error report, but turns out it didn't help. Also searched through the website but was unable to find an answer that adressed my problem.

The error screen says:
The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. [OK]

So as reinstalling didn't help me, I looked at youtube as well, and got some instructions, downloaded 32bit and 64bit versions of the following .dll files and put them into the folders, 32bit to syswow and 64bit to System32

since that didn't work as well, now I'm here. Any help?

Comment: nvm guys it is as if it was waiting for me to ask, now it works thanks fam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this 
[Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) , it should fix your problem